# How to dynamically load part of website

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is anyone knows how I can make part of my webpage dynamic like on the image 
(red dynamic, blue static) using ajax and jquery. I need just simple swapping the main page content with other 3 sliced html portions, when clicking on links.

[image]

Comment: FYI You're loading two versions of jQuery - 1.11.0 and 1.11.2. I'd remove one of them.

Comment: thanks Rory Just removed one of them, updated

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963042/simple-ajax-onclick-question)[1] pretty much answers your question, right?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963042/simple-ajax-onclick-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can use jQuery's .load() with html files too.
(I have no idea how I posted a comment earlier - I don't have enough reputation..)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".branding a").click(function() {
      $(".container").load($(this).attr("href"));

      return false;
   });
});

  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".3d a").click(function() {
      $(".container").load($(this).attr("href"));

      return false;
   });
});

   $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".apps a").click(function() {
      $(".container").load($(this).attr("href"));

      return false;
   });
});

</script>
```